# "Logitech G25 racing wheel" python api for Blender?

Tags: python, blender, bulletphysics, logitech

I'm working on a car simulation project in Blender using python scripting.

So far, I can control my vehicle(car) using simple keyboard sensors but now I want to use "Logitech G25 racing wheel" device to control my car. I googled for "Logitech G25 racing wheel python api" as hell but didn't find anything.

Is there any buddy who can help me or can post link for "Logitech G25 racing wheel python api"?

> OS/platform : Windows 7, 2GB Ram, Dual Core Processor

Comment: A game controller API would work - I don't think you need to be that specific. Also, I think you could state your OS for this question - a cross-platform answer would be better, of course, but there are OS specifc ways of getting access to the game controller inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jsbueno mentioned, you shouldn't need an API for your specific device. As long as you can find one that can interact with generic gamepad or joystick drivers, that should be sufficient.

I found a few options that may be of interest to you, but being unfamiliar with Blender, I'm not sure how easily you'll be able to integrate them into your project.  They are:

- [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html) has a [joystick API](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html)
- The [Python Computer Graphics Kit](http://cgkit.sourceforge.net/) also has a [joystick API](http://cgkit.sourceforge.net/doc2/joystick.html)
- I can't find much documentation for it, but [pyglet](http://code.google.com/p/pyglet/) appears to [support DirectInput](http://code.google.com/p/pyglet/source/browse/pyglet/input/directinput.py?r=381fcdbf382c51035f3ba8ac097f06fde4010d71)
- There's also [DirectPython](http://directpython.sourceforge.net/) and its ostensibly better-maintained successor DirectPython11 (also linked from that page), but neither seem to have much documentation

Unfortunately there's nothing that jumps out at me as especially easy to use and well-suited to your specific needs, but one of these projects may serve as a helpful starting point, at least.